# Where do the pkg-config targets get defined?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, centos7, pkg-config

When I perform the command

```
pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

The output is

> /usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig

However, there are two other `pkgconfig` directories on my system: `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

If I try

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

the result is

> Undefined variable

I also tried to

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

but the response was

> export: Command not found.

Now, I have built Gstreamer on multiple occasions and it will put the 
metadata files (gstreamer-1.0.pc) into the other pkgconfig folder (usr/local/lib/pkgconfig). (I have been able to overcome this issue by modifying the configure file, changing lib to lib64 at the libdir definition.) But I would rather understand my system rather than try work-arounds.

So two questions: where does the pkg-config program get its target directories?

And why and how do the metadata files get put into a directory that is not apparently indicated by the pkg-config program?

Comment: Thanks to @Grisha Levit for editing my poorly presented question. Neither of the answers given actually answers my two questions although l appreciate the effort to get me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the command is not working because that variable was not present
first check that variable is there or not for to do this 
execute command
env
root@localhost:/etc/apt# env
if the path is not declare in env
then do something like

root@localhost:/etc/apt# PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig 
root@localhost:/etc/apt# export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
root@localhost:/etc/apt# echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
root@localhost:/etc/apt# env

Hope this will work for you 
for any further help please post the queries with error

Comment: I found out my command export did not work because I was using tsch. If I switch to bash, I am able to use export.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a foo package, foo package has an appropriate foo.pc that gets installed in the default pkgconfig directories. If a package puts its *.pc file in a custom location, as you already know, you should set your PKG_CONFIG_PATH accordingly. So, the pkg-config will not only look in the default directories, but also in the custom path you specified in PKG_CONFIG_PATH. This guide explains it well:

[pkg-config guide](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html)